# VBA Code to set the file path dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code to read a XML as below

```
 strTargetFile = "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\XXXXXX\XXXX\XML\Details.xml"
 Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
```

Is there a way to remove this hardcoding ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your XML folder in the same folder as your workbook folder then try this:

```
sParentFolder = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)
strTargetFile = sParentFolder & "\XML\Details.xml"
Set wb =   Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile,LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
```